# C++ Constructors and Destructors - Class Triangle

Tags: c++, class, pointers, constructor, destructor

> 1. Create the class **Triangle**
> 2. Class **Triangle** must have as attributes:
>
>    - 3 sides, 3 angles, Area;
>    - 3 coordenates (Point2D), corresponding to its position on the cartesian plane (which in some cases equals 0).
> 3. Class **Triangle** must have different constructors in which the area must be calculated. It must also have access methods and other methods that may be necessary.
> 4. Implement all **Triangle** member variables with dynamic allocation of
>    memory. Allocate in constructor, deallocate in destructor (new and delete).
> 5. On main.cpp, instantiate objects and store in arrays or vectors.

This is what I have until now:

Triangle.hpp:

```
#ifndef TRIANGLE_HPP
#define TRIANGLE_HPP

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Point2d
{
public:
    int m_x, m_y;
    Point2d() : m_x(0), m_y(0){};
    Point2d(int x, int y) : m_x(x), m_y(y) {};
};

class Triangle
{
private:
    float *m_l1, *m_l2, *m_l3;
    float *m_angle1, *m_angle2, *m_angle3;
    float *m_area;

    void Initialize();

public:
    Triangle();

    Triangle(float l1, float l2, float l3);
    Triangle(float a1, float a2, float a3, float l1);
    Triangle(Point2d pt1, Point2d pt2, Point2d pt3);

    ~Triangle();

    //is_triangle();
};

#endif // TRIANGLE_HPP
```

triangle.cpp:

```
#include "triangle.hpp"
#include <cmath>

//Triangle::Triangle() : m_l1(NULL), m_l2(NULL), m_l3(NULL) {}

void Triangle::Initialize()
{
    m_l1 = new float(0);
    m_l2 = new float(0);
    m_l3 = new float(0);
    m_angle1 = new float(0);
    m_angle2 = new float(0);
    m_angle3 = new float(0);
    m_area = new float(0);
}

Triangle::Triangle()
{
    Initialize();
}

//Triangle::Triangle(float l1, float l2, float l3) : m_l1(l1), m_l2(l2), m_l3(l3){}

Triangle::Triangle(float l1, float l2, float l3)
{
    Initialize();
    *m_l1 = l1;
    *m_l2 = l2;
    *m_l3 = l3;

    //need to calculate all three angles and area
}

Triangle::Triangle(float a1, float a2, float a3, float l1)
{
    Initialize();
    *m_l1 = l1;
    *m_angle1 = a1;
    *m_angle2 = a2;
    *m_angle3 = a3;

    //calculate other 2 sides and area
}

Triangle::Triangle(Point2d pt1, Point2d pt2, Point2d pt3)
{
    Initialize();
    *m_l1 = sqrt( (pt2.m_x - pt3.m_x)*(pt2.m_x - pt3.m_x) + (pt2.m_y - pt3.m_y)*(pt2.m_y - pt3.m_y) );
    *m_l2 = sqrt( (pt1.m_x - pt3.m_x)*(pt1.m_x - pt3.m_x) + (pt1.m_y - pt3.m_y)*(pt1.m_y - pt3.m_y) );
    *m_l3 = sqrt( (pt1.m_x - pt2.m_x)*(pt1.m_x - pt2.m_x) + (pt1.m_y - pt2.m_y)*(pt1.m_y - pt2.m_y) );



}

Triangle::~Triangle()
{
    delete m_l1;
    delete m_l2;
    delete m_l3;
    delete m_angle1;
    delete m_angle2;
    delete m_angle3;
    delete m_area;
}
```

Im a little lost on how to implement calculations and all the rest, have nothing on the main yet. Can someone please help me?

Comment: What's the problem? Just make methods inside class `Triangle` for example `GetArea()`, then calculate the area in the method and return it.

Comment: Another stupid exercise. So lets abuse the rules: Replace all your pointers with `std::vector<float>`. The vector dynamically allocates memory as required by step 4. Or `std::map<std::string, float> vars;` and access all variables as `vars["name"]`.

Comment: What's the reason for using any pointers?  Those member variables could simply be `float`.  With all of that you're doing with those pointers, even a simple program like this causes issues: `int main() { Triangle t; Triangle t2 = t; }` -- You now have a double-free error on exit of `main`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming problem, but rather a math problem. Btw: Allocating values like a single `float` is terrible coding style; NEVER to this, unless explicitly asked for by a homework assignment, since it not only makes the type harder to implement without providing any benefits whatsoever, it also increases the size of the type. Since you do dynamically allocate memory, you should implement or delete the copy and move assignment&constructor. Deleting the move versions accompilishes both `Triangle(Triangle&&) = delete; Triangle& operator=(Triangle&&) = delete;`.

Comment: Pointless use of pointers.  At least make them `std::unique_ptr<float>`, to fulfill the project requirements.

Comment: *Implement all Triangle member variables with dynamic allocation of memory* -- This is the most ridiculous of these requirements, if not downright harmful.  There is no need for any pointers -- not only that, you do not learn *when* to use pointers and when not to use them with requirements like this.  Yes, pointers are used, but you don't use it for simple things like declaring `float` variables.  So now that one requirement has 3 strikes -- 1) Useless use of pointers, 2) You don't learn when to use pointers, 3) Students now drop C++ and go to another language, such as Python.

Comment: *instantiate objects and store in arrays or vectors.* -- If you then have `std::vector<Triangle>`, that simple `main` program I pointed out a few comments ago will demonstrate exactly what `std::vector` is doing to your Triangle objects -- and that is making copies.  So your program will be broken immediately when trying to accomplish requirement number 5 with the current code you have now.

Answer (score 1):

You don't initialize the pointers in your class properly and this will cause problems in the destructor if ever an allocation fails. You will `delete` random pointers.

You need to set all pointers to nullptr or allocate memory with `new` using a member initializer lists: `Triangle() : m_l1(nullptr), m_l2(new float), ... { }`. Your use of `Initialize`, while looking neater, is wrong.

Alternatively you can use inline member initialization:

```
class Triangle
{
private:
    float *m_l1{new float()};
...
};
```

With the `()` it will even initialize to 0.

Here is how it looks like for the whole class if you also reduce some of the insanity of allocating every variable separately:

```
#ifndef TRIANGLE_HPP
#define TRIANGLE_HPP 1

#include <iostream>

// use aggregate initialization `Point2d p{1,2};` so no constructors required
struct Point2d {
    int x{0}, y{0};
};

class Triangle {
private:
    float *l{new float[3]()};
    float *angle{new float[3]()};
    float *area{new float()};

public:
    Triangle();

    Triangle(float l1, float l2, float l3);
    Triangle(float a1, float a2, float a3, float l1);
    Triangle(const Point2d & pt1, const Point2d & pt2, const Point2d & pt3);

    ~Triangle();

    //is_triangle();
};

#endif // TRIANGLE_HPP
```

and

```
#include "triangle.hpp"
#include <cmath>


Triangle::Triangle() { }

Triangle::Triangle(float l1, float l2, float l3)
{
    l[0] = l1;
    l[1] = l2;
    l[2] = l3;
    //need to calculate all three angles and area
}

Triangle::Triangle(float a1, float a2, float a3, float l1)
{
    l[0] = l1;
    angle[0] = a1;
    angle[1] = a2;
    angle[2] = a3;

    //calculate other 2 sides and area
}

Triangle::Triangle(const Point2d & pt1, const Point2d & pt2, const Point2d & pt3)
: Triangle(sqrt( (pt2.x - pt3.x) * (pt2.x - pt3.x) + (pt2.y - pt3.y) * (pt2.y - pt3.y) ),
           sqrt( (pt1.x - pt3.x) * (pt1.x - pt3.x) + (pt1.y - pt3.y) * (pt1.y - pt3.y) ),
           sqrt( (pt1.x - pt2.x) * (pt1.x - pt2.x) + (pt1.y - pt2.y) * (pt1.y - pt2.y) ))
{ }

Triangle::~Triangle()
{
    delete[] l;
    delete[] angle;
    delete area;
}
```

As for computing the missing length, angles or area that is your Homework and probably better asked on a https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Unfortunately, requirement 5 in the OP's homework (`On main.cpp, instantiate objects and store in arrays or vectors.`) will result in a broken app.  But that's a side issue, and the OP should open a separate question for that.  (Nothing wrong with your answer).

Comment: Works fine if you `v.emplace_back(...)`. Otherwise you also need the copy/move constructor/operator. I just fixed what was there already, still lots to add to complete the class.